# How do I replace every dash (-) with a random number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, random, str-replace

I have have some codes like ABCDE-----ABCD----ABC--, where each (-) needs to be a random number.

I have no problem using the replace function to change a single dash to a random number, but I have no clue how to make each dash a random number. Note: each number doesn't need to be unique.

Here is where I am now, but I need the numbers to not all be the same. http://jsfiddle.net/oqrstsdm/

```
var minNumber = 1;
var maxNumber = 9;

randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);

function randomNumberFromRange(min, max) {
    var number = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));
    var str = "ABCDE-----FGABC--";
    var res = new RegExp("-", "g");
    var code = str.replace(res, number);
    document.getElementById("ccode").innerHTML = "Code: " + code;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a function as second argument in [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
var str = "ABCDE-----FGABC--";
var code = str.replace(/-/g, function() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
});
```

Comment: Nice.  A perhaps cleaner version based on the same idea: http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/5ox8bdkh/

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a while loop. Also you don't actually need a regular expression since you're just looking for a string. If you did want a regexp change `str.indexOf("-") !== -1` by `str.match(regexp) !== null`. You also wont need the `g` flag with this approach.

```
var str = "ABCDE-----FGABC--";
var number;
while (str.indexOf("-") !== -1) {
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    str = str.replace("-", number);
}
return str;
```

Output:

```
ABCDE92136FGABC38
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `replace` method, you can use the String [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to tokenize the code, and then apply an Array [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to re-join the values with the appropriate numbers substituted in.

```js
function randomNumberFromRange(min, max) {
  var str = "ABCDE-----FGABC--";

  return str.split("-").reduce(function(prev, val) {
    return prev + rand(min, max) + val;
  });
}

function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

// Demo code
document.getElementById("random").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = randomNumberFromRange(1, 9);
};
```

```html
<div id="code"></div>
<div>
  <button id="random">Get Code</button>
</div>
```